# Bigcommerce API sending no response sometimes intermittently

Tags: php, mysql, api, bigcommerce

I have Bigcommerce store and I have permission to access 60,000 API calls per hour as per Bigcommerce supporter. I have used Bigocommerce Api to fetch the all the products (50,000) from my store using one function. That function working fine for me but whenever I am trying to fetch all the products custom field name & value using below function on that time sometimes Bigcommerce API sending no response intermittently.

```
$data = Bigcommerce_Api::getProductCustomFields('Product ID');
```

First I have fetched the all the products from my store and saved it on my temporary table. After-that using php/mysql loop I have fetched all the products one by one from my table and passed the Product Id to the above Api function to fetch the product custom field name & value. But I have seen that after successfully fetching approx 30k products custom field,  for some time Bigcommerce API sending no response intermittently. I have discussed with Big-commerce supporters as well and they told me that there was no issue from their end & it was set up correctly.

Please suggest me how can I resolve that issue.

thanks in advance

Comment: Executing the same function 30k times doesn't seem very efficient. Maybe explore what your other options are with the API? Curious, are you dealing with empty names and values?

Comment: Yeah there may be some empty field values for some of products. But it's not the issue. what do you mean by 30k times ??? I have told that using one function I am able to fetch 30k products custom field values, that doesn't means that same function executes 30k times.

Comment: Hello, would you please post more of your source code here so we can see how it is functioning? Thanks!

Comment: There is no more source code. If you worked with API of bigcommerce  you will surely aware with that. I have getting 20,000 api request per hour as per API header remaining response.But as per bigcommerce it is 60k per hour for my store.